# Where are the stairs?

Tags: rogue

After trying a lot of roguelikes, I decided I wanted to try the "trope namer": Rogue itself.

Pretty soon, however, I found a problem.

```
                            ----------------------
   ------------------    ###+                    |              -------
   |                |    #  |                    |              |     |
   |                +#####  |                 %  |              |     |
   ----------------+-       |                    |              ---+---
                   #        ----------------------         #########
                 ###                                       #
       ----------+--                    -------            #
       |           |                    |     |          --+------------
       |           |                   #+     |          |             |
       |           |                   #|     +#####     |             |
       |           +####################-------    ######+             |
       -----------+-                                     |             |
                  #                                      -+-------------
                  ###                                     ###########
                    #                                               #
                    #                                         ------+--
    ----------------+-----                                    |.......|
    |                    |                                    |.......|
    |                    |                                    |..@....|
    |                    |                                    ---------
    ----------------------
Level: 1  Gold: 71     Hp: 15(15)   Str: 16(16) Arm: 4  Exp: 2/12
```

...where are the stairs up and down?

Comment: Rogue, unlike later games it inspired, has only a single stairway (%) on each floor.  Until you find the amulet, all stairways are down stairways.  Afterward, all stairways are up stairways.  See the note on stairs [here](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Rogue_level).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the <kbd>%</kbd> sign is the stairs, but I could be wrong, as the version of Rogue I played used a green symbol with three bars as the stairs.  Stand on top of the <kbd>%</kbd> sign and press less than (<kbd><</kbd>).  That should take you down a level.

Comment: Whoops, that was it!